# Help! Parity Error: account not found for current chain (ropsten)

Tags: parity

I have downloaded Parity and its connecting with accounts created from Pariy-Ui, When I tries to connect Parity using an account created from MetaMask Chrome Extension, then its showing below error message:

```
Account 0x3314…b168 not found for the current chain. You can create an account via RPC, UI or `parity account new --chain ropsten --keys-path /home/user/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys`.
```

I am using below command in order to run Parity and unlock account:

```
parity --chain ropsten --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,parity" --unlock 0x00E76a64CF25d7T23rRYE0aD74as214Bc2F0F1 --password $HOME/password1.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated.